# How to mount volume of airflow worker to airflow kubernetes pod operator?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, airflow

I am trying to using the kubernetes pod operator in airflow, and there is a directory that I wish to share with kubernetes pod on my airflow worker, is there is a way to mount airflow worker's directory to kubernetes pod?

I tried with the code below, and the volumn seems not mounted successfully.

```
import datetime
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from airflow.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.kubernetes.volume import Volume
from airflow.kubernetes.volume_mount import VolumeMount


class TestMailAlarm(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.namespace = "test-namespace"
        self.image = "ubuntu:16.04"
        self.name = "default"

        self.cluster_context = "default"

        self.dag_id = "test_dag"
        self.task_id = "root_test_dag"
        self.execution_date = datetime.datetime.now()

        self.context = {"dag_id": self.dag_id,
                        "task_id": self.task_id,
                        "execution_date": self.execution_date}

        self.cmds = ["sleep"]
        self.arguments = ["100"]

        self.volume_mount = VolumeMount('test',
                                        mount_path='/tmp',
                                        sub_path=None,
                                        read_only=False)

        volume_config = {
            'persistentVolumeClaim':
                {
                    'claimName': 'test'
                }
        }
        self.volume = Volume(name='test', configs=volume_config)

        self.operator = KubernetesPodOperator(
            namespace=self.namespace, image=self.image, name=self.name,
            cmds=self.cmds,
            arguments=self.arguments,
            startup_timeout_seconds=600,
            is_delete_operator_pod=True,
            # the operator could run successfully but the directory /tmp is not mounted to kubernetes operator
            volume=[self.volume],
            volume_mount=[self.volume_mount],
            **self.context)

    def test_execute(self):
        self.operator.execute(self.context)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example in the docs seems pretty similar to your code, only the parameters are plurals **`volume_mounts`** and  **`volumes`**. For your code it would look like this:

```
self.operator = KubernetesPodOperator(
            namespace=self.namespace, image=self.image, name=self.name,
            cmds=self.cmds,
            arguments=self.arguments,
            startup_timeout_seconds=600,
            is_delete_operator_pod=True,
            # the operator could run successfully but the directory /tmp is not mounted to kubernetes operator
            volumes=[self.volume],
            volume_mounts=[self.volume_mount],
            **self.context)
```

Comment: I tried with the example in the doc, and the log always display: Event: test-302a784b had an event of type Pending, the kubernetes throws an error: persistentvolumeclaim "test-volume" not found, could you share you opinions on this problem? I am new to kubernetes and blocked here:(

Comment: @buxizhizhoum, I edited my answer to be more specific. Did you already do this and you're getting the error you posted?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I still get the error with the new answer, but should I create the PV in kubernetes before I try to mount a directory on it? I checked the kubernetes cluster and there is no PV named "test", is this the reason of this error?

Comment: Plaes teake look for this [example](http://space.af/blog/2018/09/30/gke-airflow-cloud-composer-and-persistent-volumes/)
It looks like you should create pv and pvc and update your DAG with those information.

Comment: @Hanx， you are right, there should be a pv created before mounting, since there is no pv in my test env, and I always failed to mount it.